# sh.exe": clip: command not found

Tags: git, github

Friends 
Im trying to copy the ssh key on to the clipboard and while on the git bash, Im getting

```
$ clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
sh.exe": clip: command not found
```

Im using Win7 , I tried using the windows command prompt but no luck,

Please let me know any alternate way

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with git or GitHub; it's just about clip.exe not being in your path.

Comment: Thanks , any idea adding clip.exe to the path ?

Comment: open a normal cmd.exe, cd to your .ssh folder and "clip <id_rsa.pub"

Answer (score 14):

`clip.exe` should be in `C:\Windows\System32\` or `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\`. You can check if those folders are in your path by doing `echo $PATH`. If they aren't (which would surprise me), you can add them:

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows\SysWOW64"
```

It's probably more likely `clip.exe` doesn't exist on your system at all.

However, there's a much simpler way you can manipulate the Windows clipboard from Git Bash (or, for that matter, Cygwin): the clipboard device file, `/dev/clipboard`.

To write to it:

```
$ echo "test" >/dev/clipboard
```

To read from it:

```
$ cat </dev/clipboard
```

The equivalent of your command would be:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >/dev/clipboard
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for what it's worth...

I'm running Windows 10 with WSL 2 all configured and I found that `clip.exe` is present on my system at `C:\Windows\System32\` and my path does already include `C:\Windows\System32\`. All I needed to do was to add `.exe` to the command in this obvious (to me, anyway) location:

```
clip.exe < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: I also use Windows 10 with WSL 2 and your suggestion helps.